Intraday government bond data
Is there any place where I can access intraday government bond price data, historical and/or ticker?
Thanks

Yes, IBKR has free historical Intraday data for bonds; I just checked the August 15th T-Bill. You can use either reqhistoricaldata or, if you want even more granularity, reqHistoricalTicks.
